# Necesito analizar y comparar una una cadena con una sub cadena

Tags: ruby

Quiero seleccionar una sub cadena obtenida a partir de un archivo de texto y analizarla.

Archivo de texto:

```
NADSU 78000mc0cl0Css
NADBY 7808810008659
PAT 1 21D 089
```

Necesito leer y posterior analizar linea por linea de un archivo .txt luego de eso quisiera verificar mediante un ciclo if o case podria ser que se cumplan los paramentros. aclaro el arvhivo txt tiene cerca de 300 lineas

Los tres primeros caracteres deben ser letras con un formato específico,
el siguiente normalmente es el 4 carácter o 5 que tiene un numero depende de ese numero significa algo y el ultimo es el numero de  orden de compra o la cantidad o tipo de envoltura.

Esto es una idea generalizada solo estoy dando lo mínimo para entender.

Ejemplo de dos casos reales de la linea a analizar:

```
NADBY 7808810008659
```

Las Letras `NAD` es la *Orden de compra* `BY` es el *Proveedor* y  el restante es el *Número de orden de compra*.

```
PAT 1 21D 089
```

`PAT` significa *Tipo de pago*, el primer número es el *Tipo de pago* donde: si es `1` el *Tipo de pago* es *contado*, si es `2` es *Crédito*. El del medio `21d` es cantidad de *días para emitir despacho* y el `089` es la cantidad de días para pagar.

```
NADSU 78000mc0cl0Css
```

Las letras`NAD` son para *Orden de compra* y `BY` es el *Comprador*; `Css` equivale a *cajas* pero puede ser `ss`, que equivale a *minicajas*.

```
<% fileopen ('nombre_doc.txt',r) do |fichero1| %>
  <% fileopen ('copianombre_doc.txt',w) do |fichero2| %>
    <% while linea= fichero1.gets %>
      <% fichero1=gsub(/\s+/,'') %>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/117333/edit) tu respuesta agregando el trabajo/esfuerzo previo

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más específico en el resultado esperado? Por ejemplo, ¿qué resultado deseas obtener al procesar la cadena `NADBY 7808810008659`?

Comment: la traduccion de eso me va arrojar NADBY nombre del proveedor, el primer numero que es 7 me dice que es de la region metropolitana los ultimos dos cuantas cajas compro, quedaria algo asi NADBY = region metropolina, codigo proveedor, cantidad de cajas compradas 59

Comment: Cuando termine de analizar y armar cada linea tendria todo un informe con codigo de cliente nombre direccion fecha cantidad de objetos comprados en fin todos los detalles de una orden de compra normal y corriente

Comment: gerry me podrias dar tu mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...quedaria algo asi NADBY = region metropolina, codigo proveedor,
>   cantidad de cajas compradas 59.

Si el formato es fijo, entonces podrías hacer referencia a las posiciones de cada caracter, por ejemplo:

```
string = "NADBY 7808810008659"
#=> "NADBY 7808810008659"

if string.split(" ").first.size == 5
  clave     = string[0..4]   #=> "NADBY"
  region    = string[6]      #=> "7"
  proveedor = string[7...-2] #=> "8088100086"
  cajas     = string[-2..-1] #=> "59"

  resultado = "#{clave} = región #{region}, #{proveedor}, cantidad de cajas compradas #{cajas}."
  #=> "NADBY = región 7, 8088100086, cantidad de cajas compradas 59."
else
  # código para procesar cadenas que no inician con 5 letras
end
```

Utilizando `[]` sobre tu *string* puedes obtener el caracter que está en esa una posición específica a través de su índice (inicia en `0`) o bien, utilizando rangos (e.g. `0..4`) puedes obtener una parte del *string*.

---

**Respuesta original**

También podrías utilizar el método `String#start_with?` para buscar las cadenas que inicien con `"ABC-2"`. Claro que antes tendrías que convertir tu *string* actual en un arreglo para comparar cada una; por ejemplo:

```
string  = "ACB-1234567890123 BCD-1234567890123 ABC-2134567890123"
#=> "ACB-1234567890123 BCD-1234567890123 ABC-2134567890123"

string.split(" ").each_with_object([]) do |s, numbers|
  if s.start_with?("ABC-2")
    # aquí tu código para hacer
    # algo específico...

    numbers << s.split("-").last
  end
end
#=> ["2134567890123"]
```

Lo que hace este código es:

- `.split(" ")` separa todos los *strings* y los convierte en un arreglo (utiliza la variable `s` para identificar cada uno).
- `each_with_object([])` itera el arreglo de *strings* y genera un arreglo nuevo (representado en la variable `numbers`).
- `if s.start_with?("ABC-2")` evalúa si el *string* en turno cumple con las condiciones.
- `numbers << s.split("-").last` divide el *string* actual en letras y números y agrega los números al arreglo `numbers` (cuando el `if` se cumple).

El resultado es un arreglo con 1 elemento, el cual representa el número del único *string* que cumplió con la condición (*"que las primeras tres letras sean ABC y el primer numero sea 2"*).

Comment: hola gerry muchas gracias eres grande.... super bien explicada la respuesta. otra consulta en mi caso no creo que pueda poner cada variable en una matriz ya que viene de una orden de compra codificada que leo de un txt que esta encriptado. tengo una sentencia que lee linea por linea del txt y de esa manera quería proceder aunque estoy dispuesto a cambiar de idea si simplifica el trabajo.. y por ultimo tenga una sola linea tiene un formato ABC-2134567890123CS que lo ultimo indica que son cajas, en ese caso abra un comando que sea algo asi s.final_with?

Comment: @JonathanZambrano Una opción es eliminar el uso de `string.split(" ")` y utilizar la lógica del `if` dentro de tu sentencia que ya lee línea por línea. ¿Podrías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/117333/edit) tu pregunta y mostrar el código donde lees el archivo de texto y procesas cada línea? Con ello podría actualizar mi respuesta acordemente. Incluso lo mejor sería que agregaras un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: ya actualice mi pregunta si puedes darle una ojeada seria genial. a ver si me puedes ayudar de ante mano gracias

Comment: @JonathanZambrano Mira la respuesta actualizada, espero te sirva de guía.

Comment: gerry esta muy buena tu solucion de verdad, creo que entre las dos respuestas soluciono mis dudas, en la ultima actualizacion hay un detalle recuerdad que analiza linea por linea en un ciclo for 1 to i, entonces va a pasar el primer valor bien y el segundo que es NADSU tambien va a pasar la validacion... if string.split(" ").start_with?("NADSU") ? seria valida esa sentencia o algo similar?

Comment: @JonathanZambrano Casi, la validación sería: `if string.start_with?("NADSU")`, no necesitas hacer el `split` pues solo necesitas evaluar si la cadena empieza con `"NADSU"`.

Comment: gracias Gerry, de verdad mil gracias... si necesitas algo en .net o c# no dudes en contactarme... voy ahora a probar q tal aunq logicamente funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar una expresión regular para extraer el valor del string:

```
  param = 'ACB-1234567890123'
  regex = /ACB-(\d+)/
  if param =~ regex
    param.match(regex)[1] # => "1234567890123"
  end
```

Comment: no habia visto esa sentencia en otro lado gracias por el aporte, adicionalmente como podria validar que ejemplo el valor del primer numero me signica algo y el segundo otra cosa.?

Comment: hay alguna sentencia que sea como vb.net o c# que cuente los caracteres y te permita compararlos con el punto de referencia?